# redshift update command to set value from another column, this column name is identifier

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have an existing table with lots of data in Redshift. This table has a column named "timestamp" with data type varchar. I have created a new column named "timestamp_dt" with data type timestamp with out time zone.

**Now I want to pull data from "timestamp" column to "timestamp_dt" column.**

Running below command would not work because timestamp is a keyword
and adding double quote would not work because then it will be treated like a string instead to column name.

```
Update table 
Set timestamp_dt = timestamp
```

Thank you in advance for comments and/or answer.

Comment: Double quotes will **not** make it be treated as a strings. Strings are denoted by single quotes in SQL: `'this is a string'` `"column_name"`

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name. It was helpful and directed me to right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There was also another problem then it initially appear. Double quote was working but then it needs casting. Thus below solves the issue.

```
Update bannersession
Set timestamp_dt = "timestamp"::TIMESTAMP
```